# How in methods function call variable from vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my `Vue.js` component, I have `v-select` element. When the user selects some value in that widget I call `toDo` function which is defined in `methods` block. As you can see in that function I want to know the value of the getter called `filters`. Unfortunately, it returns me `undefined`. At the same time in DevTools of Vue I notice that this getter has value. How in function correctly take the value of the getter?

**QUESTION:**

I use `filters` in the template and they are displayed on the interface without any problem. But in `toDo` function, the same `filters` return `undefined` result. I want to understand this strange behavior.

```
<div
    v-for="filter in filters"
    :key="filter.id">
    <v-checkbox
        v-for="(item, index) in filter.values"
        :label="filter.description_values[index]"
        :value="item"
        :key="item"
        v-model="filter.selected_values"
        hide-details>
    </v-checkbox>
    <v-select
        v-if="filter.widget==='single_dropdown'"
        v-model="filter.selected_values"
        :items="filter.filter_values"
        label="Select ..."
        dense
        solo
        @change="toDo">
    </v-select>
</div>

***
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('store', [
    'filters'
  ]),
},
methods: {
  toDo: async (value) {
    await console.log(this.filters) // result: undefined
  }
}
***
```

**Vuex Storage**:

```
import { api } from '../../services/api'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    filters: null
  },
  getters: {
    filters: state => state.filters
  },
  mutations: {
    setStateValue: (state, {key, value}) => {
       state[key] = value
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getFilters: async (context) => {
      await api.get('/api/filters').then((response) => {
        context.commit('setStateValue', {
          key: 'filters',
          value: response.data
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mapGetters computed, call all getters inside a one Array:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['store', 'filters']),
},
```

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstood the question. `mapGetters` is installed correctly. Why when I try to use the `filters` variable in the `toDo` function, I get an `undefined` result. At the same time in DevTools of Vue I see that the `filters` variable has value. I hope you understand me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I use `filters` in the template and they are displayed on the interface. You can check my post again. I add the template. But in `toDo` function, the same `filters` return `undefined` result. I want to understand this strange behavior.

Comment: I understand, where do you call `toDo` function?

Comment: Well, as I said before in the post I have `v-select` element. I add that widget, you can check the post. When the user selects some value in that widget I call `toDo` function which is defined in methods block.

Answer (score 0):

The `filters` getter is at the root of your store; it's not inside a module. You can access it without namespacing:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['filters']),
},
```

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstood the question. `mapGetters` is installed correctly. Why when I try to use the `filters` variable in the `toDo` function, I get an `undefined` result. At the same time in DevTools of Vue I see that the `filters` variable has value. I hope you understand me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I use `filters` in the template and they are displayed on the interface. You can check my post again. I add the template. But in `toDo` function, the same `filters` return `undefined` result. I want to understand this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

At first - if Vuex code you provided is your main store (not a part of a module) you should remove `namespaced: true,` - it is used solely for vuex modules.

and if Vuex code you provided is not part of a Vuex module you should simply map getters this way:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['filters']),
},
```

More info - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstood the question. `mapGetters` is installed correctly. Why when I try to use the `filters` variable in the `toDo` function, I get an `undefined` result. At the same time in DevTools of Vue I see that the `filters` variable has value. I hope you understand me. I use `filters` in the template and they are displayed on the interface without any problem. You can check my post again. I add the template. But in `toDo` function, the same `filters` return `undefined` result. I want to understand this strange behavior. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It seems like we can't use computed getters inside methods in vue.js, right?!

Comment: No, we can use them. one thing I've missed is that you use async function with await for console.log (it returns undefined)? what is it for? try removing async / await

Comment: You are right. At first, I used `async await` function in `methods` block. Instead of that now I use the simple function. It works after this changes. Can you add this information to your post, please. I will mark it as the correct answer.